# FlutterView.send called on a detached view, channel=plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I'm trying to create a responsive listview that when data updated, the list automatically refreshes. I'm using streams and firestore database to do that but every time data changes this message pops in log:

```
D/FlutterNativeView(15626): FlutterView.send called on a detached view, channel=plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore
```

And here is my page code:
https://gist.github.com/mahdizakizadeh/09df2d5f85c4c23294cfb2c423707b20

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. I think `StreamZip` waits until all streams emit once then run builder function. I think I should use Something like `Observable.merge` or `StreamGroup.merge` but I have problem with that too and it's a little tricky to handle that. So for now I'm using two nested `StreamBuilder`s and it's works fine

Answer (score 1):

Since you're updating the Widget-Tree i would wrap it in a Statefull Widget. That may fix the problem, but i am not sure.